# Windows phone custom user control not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a windows phone silverlight 8.1 app. I have created user control using Blend. Code for user control:

```
<Grid>
    <Ellipse Width="173" Height="173">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Images/abc.jpg"/>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

I am using this User control to make a live tile using a WritableBitmap. Above code works fine if I remove Image from Ellipse and replace it with color, live tile is created same as user control. When I use Image to fill Ellipse it creates a blank tile.
I just found out if I add image using Image control it shows on the tile but if use image as ellipse fill or Grid background, it doesn't show up on the tile. What's wrong?

Comment: What's the 'Build Action' of the Image file. Content or Resource ?

Comment: @ChrisShao I changed to resource, still not working, also copied to output directory

Comment: If build action is 'Resource', maybe you can not use it in this way. I think you can create the user control in your page to test if it can be displayed in your page.

Comment: @ChrisShao yes it is displayed in the page

Comment: OK. Maybe you can change a smaller size image to test. If the image is large, it may not be rendered completely before tile generation.

Comment: @ChrisShao updated my question

Comment: If background or fill brush can't be shown. Can you try to Clip the image instead of using it as backgound of grid?

Comment: @ChrisShao Yes I can add image seperately